# Behaviour of std::move operation in c++11

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

struct A {
    std::string s;
    A() : s("test") {}
    A(const A& o) : s(o.s) { std::cout << "move failed!\n"; }
    A(A&& o) : s(std::move(o.s)) {}
    A& operator=(const A&) { std::cout << "copy assigned\n"; return *this; }
    A& operator=(A&& other) {
        s = std::move(other.s);
        std::cout << "move assigned\n";`enter code here`
        return *this;
    }
};

A f(A a) { return a; }

struct B : A {
    std::string s2;
    int n;
    // implicit move assignment operator B& B::operator=(B&&)
    // calls A's move assignment operator
    // calls s2's move assignment operator
    // and makes a bitwise copy of n
};

struct C : B {
    ~C() {}; // destructor prevents implicit move assignment
};

struct D : B {
    D() {}
    ~D() {}; // destructor would prevent implicit move assignment
    //D& operator=(D&&) = default; // force a move assignment anyway 
};

int main()
{
    A a1, a2;
    std::cout << "Trying to move-assign A from rvalue temporary\n";
    a1 = f(A()); // move-assignment from rvalue temporary
    std::cout << "Trying to move-assign A from xvalue\n";
    a2 = std::move(a1); // move-assignment from xvalue

    std::cout << "Trying to move-assign B\n";
    B b1, b2;
    std::cout << "Before move, b1.s = \"" << b1.s << "\"\n";
    b2 = std::move(b1); // calls implicit move assignment
    std::cout << "After move, b1.s = \"" << b1.s << "\"\n";

    std::cout << "Trying to move-assign C\n";
    C c1, c2;
    c2 = std::move(c1); // calls the copy assignment operator

    std::cout << "Trying to move-assign D\n";
    D d1, d2;
//  d2 = std::move(d1);
}
```

While executing `a2 = std::move(a1)` statement, the behaviour is different from  executing the statement `b2 = std::move(b1)`. In the below statement the `b1.s` is not becoming empty after the move operation while `a1.s` is becoming empty after move operation.

Can anyone tell what exactly is happening there?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: @Praetorian Or, in other words, why do you think your compiler is C++11 compliant...

Comment: What @Yakk means is that this might be an artifact of gcc's reference counted `std::string` implementation, which is not C++11 compliant. In any case, there are no guarantees about a moved from object, other than being in a *valid but unspecified state*, so the library might implement move assignment as a call to `swap`, which would leave the source containing whatever the destination contained, or it might implement it as a call to `assign` (or something similar) which would leave the source string empty.

Comment: @praet or msvc2013, which does not auto generate move ctors.  Lots of reasons not to trust the compiler.  Beyond that and above, we have sso which makes short moves a copy.

Answer (score 2):

One of the great (and constant) misconceptions about C++11 and rvalue references is that `std::move` does something to an object (or something on that order).

It doesn't. `std::move` really just casts its parameter to rvalue reference type and returns that. Anything done to the object happens in the move constructor, move assignment operator (etc.) based on the fact that the version that takes an rvalue reference is invoked (instead of one taking a value or lvalue reference).

As far as the specific question you asked goes, at least based on the comments in your code, you seem to have some misunderstandings. The comment on `a2=std::move(a1);` says you're doing a "move assignment from an xvalue". That's...misleading at best. An xvalue is a value that's going to eXpire immediately. It's pretty much for the return value from a function:

```
Foo &&bar() { 
    Foo f;
    // ...
    return f;
}
```

In this case, `bar()` is an `xvalue` because `bar` returns an rvalue reference to an object that expires (goes out of scope) as function finishes execution.

As far as the specific question you asked goes, I suspect it mostly comes down to a question of whether (and if so, exactly how) your standard library implements the move constructor for `std::string`. Just for example, when using g++ (4.9.1) I get the same result you do--`b1.s` contains `test` both before and after being used as the source of a move. On the other hand, if I use MS VC++ 14 CTP, I get `b1.s="test"` before the move and `b1.s=""` after the move. Although I haven't tested it, I'd expect results with Clang to be the same. In short, it looks like gcc's standard library doesn't really implement `move` assignment/construction for `std::string` (yet--at least as of v 4.9--I haven't looked at 5.0 yet).

Comment: The `f` in `bar()` isn't an xvalue; it's an lvalue. There's a special rule that says that in this situation overload resolution is "performed as if the object were designated by an rvalue", note the contrafactual conditional. For `A f(A a) { return a; }`, the result of `f(A())` is a prvalue.

Comment: Oops--thanks--meant to return an rvalue reference, but somehow left out the crucial `&&` on the return type...

Comment: The expression `bar()` is an xvalue, but `f` in `bar()` is not.

Answer (score 1):

Usually move assignment is implemented as a swap on `std::string`, so why should the string become empty since it's always initialized with `"test"`?

Where do you see that `a1.s` is becoming empty since there is no print of it?

I don't see any strange behavior [here](http://ideone.com/cY9w2X). Both are treated in the same way.

Comment: @ Jack I have observed this while debugging the code. The a1.s value changes after the move operation but the same is not happening with b1.s  and both of them are strings. Though a1 and b1 are  lvalues am converting it in to r value by using std::move()...so why is this happening. And on top of this in the first case it is not calling copy constructor where as in the second case it is calling copy constructor. Can I know how std::move() works in derived class